# Generic jQuery function to enable/disabled drop down list based on a checkbox value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I need to write a **generic** jQuery method enable/disable a drop down list based on a checkbox value.

I have 2 components (each has a checkbox and a drop down list) and I don't want to write the exact same method twice, only with different id's of the checkbox and the drop down list.

I thought maybe to use the class selector to find the checkboxes (that will have the same class) and somehow go to their parent and search for a drop down list child of that parent (and of course make sure that both of the checkbox and dropdown list will be siblings under the same parent)

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. What do you need from us? Please [edit] you question to include what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a working example of a generic jQuery method that uses classes like you asked:

```js
$('.checkbox-class').on('change', function() {
  let parent = $(this).parent();
  let dropdown = parent.find('.dropdown-class');
  dropdown.prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="component">
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-class">
  <select class="dropdown-class" disabled>
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [DOM traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). If you want to be very generic, technically you don't need `classes` or `ids`, you can just use you elements themself.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).siblings('select').prop('disabled', !this.checked)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <select disabled>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
  </select>
</div>
```